# In the collage pan of Rose's pictures in Titanic (1997), what was this picture intended to exhibit?

Tags: titanic

Picture's source is [the 53 s instant](https://youtu.be/xPlGPpS9hl0?t=53s).

[image]

Comment: That she went fishing, and caught a fish?

Comment: @Longshanks That's a fish? Sorry, I failed to discern it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She's gone fishin'

Here's the full [image](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/3b/af/08/3baf08760194106fe8641d1ed567f4d7.jpg):
[image: Rose with a fish]

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal Googled 'Rose Dawson fish'.

Comment: Thanks. A better question: did you recognise her as fishing before, or after, finding the full-sized photo?

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal Before. I've seen the film before and to me is quite clearly someone holding a rod, next to the tail of a fish. I'd say it's quite a common pose, and fish are often hung that way for preparing/taking a good photo.